# Access main function from component

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

How do I get "close" button to run `runFunction()` from within component to outside declaration? `FxGlobals.topLevelApplication` doesn't seem to be working for this.

```
<fx:Declarations>
        <fx:Component className="MyNativeWindow">
            <s:Window>
                <s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="100%">
                <s:backgroundFill>
                <s:LinearGradient>
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0x555555"/>
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0x777777"/>
                    </s:LinearGradient>
                </s:backgroundFill>
                <mx:Button y="263" x="420" label="close" click="runFunction();this.close()"/>   
                </s:BorderContainer>
            </s:Window>
        </fx:Component>
    </fx:Declarations>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you shouldn't be doing this, more on that in a moment...

If you must do this, (say you have to for some business reason)

You should be able to access the top level application like this...

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Component className="MyNativeWindow">
        <s:Window>
            <s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="100%">
            <s:backgroundFill>
            <s:LinearGradient>
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x555555"/>
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x777777"/>
                </s:LinearGradient>
            </s:backgroundFill>
            <mx:Button y="263" x="420" label="close" click="(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as MyApplicationType).runFunction();this.close()"/>   
            </s:BorderContainer>
        </s:Window>
    </fx:Component>
</fx:Declarations>
```

Replacing `MyApplicationType` with the type of your application.

Now, further to my, **do not do this** note, above. Your component shouldn't be calling dependent functions this way, instead you should be handling this button `click` event using a handler function, which then triggers a component level event which is handled at each level up the component tree, all the way to the Application, if that is where this event should be handled.

However, just telling you to do this without knowing the rest of your application structure won't help much, chances are you will need to create the mess before you understand why it should be cleaned.

But as a helpful tip, always try to modularize your application, by separating functional responsibilities into appropriate classes.

Comment: Yeah, this is one easy way and I manage to try another method using dispatch event in component with metaevent. As in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701343/flex-4-accessing-public-method-in-main-application-from-component Is this what you mean?

Comment: yeah... that's one implementation. `MyApplicationType` would be whatever your application is called. (that would be it's type.)

Comment: The Event model in Flex is an example of the GOF Design Pattern "Observer" ... that is objects that are unknown to another object can subscribe to messages it sends (which they can then do things relevant to the message), so in the case of Flex, these messages are an `Event` which an object `dispatches` ... Flex also supports bubbling so you can listen for an event anywhere on the display tree... so you don't even need to know what object dispatched it, just the `Event` type your observer object is interested in. Google for Flex Event Bubbling and read the articles you find.